# Should I use "at soonest" or "as soonest"?

Tags: phrases

My sentence goes like this: "Please let us know **at soonest** if you can help us." Is it correct? And, if yes, is "as soonest" a possible alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think perhaps you should consider using [ell.se].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polite alternatives to "as soon as possible"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69101/polite-alternatives-to-as-soon-as-possible)

Comment: also related: [“At my earliest convenience”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/191750/at-my-earliest-convenience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Soonest](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soonest) is used to say 'as quickly as is reasonable', it is the [superlative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superlative) form of the word of soon. (soon -> sooner -> soonest). "As soon as possible" is what you should use:

> Please let us know **as soon as possible** (or as early as possible) if you can help us.

Usage in a response:

> I don't know for sure, the **soonest** I can know is later this evening.

OR

> The **soonest** possible time I can let you know is at 5 pm.

You may hear someone say to someone else **"see you soonest"** but it's [colloquial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/colloquial) and what they mean is **"see you in a flash"** or **"see you as soon as I can"** or **"see you very soon"**.

Comment: Where exactly might you hear someone say “see you soonest”? I’ve never heard anyone say it. Sounds like the kind of thing you might find in Indian English, though I have no idea if it does actually exist there.

Comment: i agree, it's a bit unconventional, `out of everyone, I'll see you the soonest` is probably more conventional. one of my aunts used to use `see you soonest`, it's colloquial but a little old-school.